# Storing and accessing request-response wide object

Tags: django, ldap

I need to store a created/open LDAP connection, so multiple models, views and so on can reuse a single connection rather than creating a new one each time. This connection should be open when first required during a request and closed when sending a response (done generating the page). The connection should not be shared between different requests/responses.

What is the way to do it? Where to store the connection and how to ensure it is eventually closed?

A bit more info. As an additional information source, I use LDAP connections. LDAP data contains details I cannot store in the database (redundancy/consistency reasons), e.g. MS Exchange mailing groups. I might need some LDAP data in multiple points, different objects/instances should access it during response generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to store the connection resource so that it can be shared across your components is to use [thread local storage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local).

For example, in `myldap.py`:

```
import threading
_local = theading.local()

def get_ldap_connection():
    if not hasattr(_local, 'ldap_connection') or _local.ldap_connection is None:
        _local.ldap_connection = create_ldap_connection()

    return _local.ldap_connection

def close_ldap_connection():
    if hasattr(_local, 'ldap_connection') and _local.ldap_connection is not None:
        close_ldap_connection(_local.ldap_connection)
        _local.ldap_connection = None
```

So the first time `myldap.get_ldap_connection` is called from a specific thread it will open the connection. Subsequent calls from the same thread will reuse the connection.

To ensure the connection is closed when you have finished working, you could implement a [Django middleware component](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/). Amongst other things this will allow you to specify a hook that gets invoked [after the view has returned it's response object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#hooks-and-application-order).

The middleware can then invoke `myldap.close_ldap_connection()` like this:

```
import myldap

Class CloseLdapMiddleware(object):  
    def process_response(self, response):  
        myldap.close_ldap_connection()
        return response
```

Finally you will need to add your middleware in `settings.py` `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'path.to.CloseLdapMiddleWare',
    ...
]
```

Comment: Good idea, I haven't thought of using middleware :) However usage of thread local will not fit the concepts of our software, therefore I will wait a little longer before accepting.

Comment: The only alternative I know to using thread local (or a variant thereof) is to store information on the request object. The downside of that approach however is that you then have to pass the request object to every function that may require the ldap connection - which can be quite heavy depending on your exact needs and architecture.